# Why don't I receive the emails forwarded by Postfix?

Tags: postfix, smtp, centos6, tls, mail-forwarding

My desired Postfix configuration is to forward all incoming mails according to virtual aliases and be able to send outgoing mails via SMTP and TLS. Sending already works, but the forwarding does not.

When I send a mail from `myname@gmail.com` to `test@mydomain1.com` it should be forwarded back to the Gmail account. However, I don't receive the mail in Gmail. I'm not completely sure how to read the log but it seems like the rewriting works and the mail was sent out as well.

**/var/log/maillog**

```
Jul  9 18:17:11 sXXXXXXXX postfix/postfix-script[17039]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jul  9 18:17:12 sXXXXXXXX postfix/master[17040]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul  9 18:18:12 sXXXXXXXX postfix/smtpd[17061]: connect from mail-lb0-f169.google.com[209.85.217.169]
Jul  9 18:18:12 sXXXXXXXX postfix/smtpd[17061]: F2C3543B8114: client=mail-lb0-f169.google.com[209.85.217.169]
Jul  9 18:18:13 sXXXXXXXX postfix/cleanup[17066]: F2C3543B8114: message-id=<CAGRzetbJ85Ss5FdSn6g=HV5HrCO9=HnZTx1w+4qVfH-r0LfaOQ@mail.gmail.com>
Jul  9 18:18:13 sXXXXXXXX postfix/qmgr[17043]: F2C3543B8114: from=<myname@gmail.com>, size=1672, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  9 18:18:13 sXXXXXXXX postfix/smtpd[17061]: disconnect from mail-lb0-f169.google.com[209.85.217.169]
Jul  9 18:18:13 sXXXXXXXX postfix/smtp[17067]: F2C3543B8114: to=<myname@gmail.com>, orig_to=<test@mydomain1.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.27]:25, delay=0.53, delays=0.11/0.05/0.16/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1436458693 ew5si6226110wid.61 - gsmtp)
Jul  9 18:18:13 sXXXXXXXX postfix/qmgr[17043]: F2C3543B8114: removed
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# ...

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain         =
smtpd_sasl_security_options     = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    = permit_sasl_authenticated,
                                  permit_mynetworks,
                                  reject_unauth_destination

smtp_use_tls                    = yes
smtp_tls_cert_file              = /etc/postfix/certs/cert.pem
smtp_tls_key_file               = /etc/postfix/certs/cert_key.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile                 = /etc/postfix/certs/cacert.pem

smtpd_use_tls                   = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file             = /etc/postfix/certs/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file              = /etc/postfix/certs/cert_key.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile                = /etc/postfix/certs/cacert.pem

tls_random_source               = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Comment: Check in Spam, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I already did. Maybe it's a port issue? Or it's forcing TLS but it's not supported?

Comment: Your mail was delivered to Gmail successfully. There is no "port issue" or "forcing TLS but it's not supported" to be concerned about. If the mail isn't visible to you, it's because Gmail did something to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have send email email with sender and 'final' recipient was same, i.e. your sender is myname@gmail.com and the recipient (after aliasing) is myname@gmail.com too. Based on this fact, perhaps your problem was related to this KB: [Why do I not receive mail I send to myself via a forward or mailing list?](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=176620087)

> Gmail (and the gmail-based IU Umail system) has a rather annoying "feature" whereby it will not show you email you send yourself. This affects email you send via mailing lists, google groups, and email forwards (such as a .forward file in your SoIC Linux account). This feature is described in this gmail support page: [Not receiving email from groups](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6588?hl=en).
>
> **Technically, it will not show you messages you send when they arrive back at gmail with the same Message-ID**. This is typically the case for mailing lists and *.forward*. If you are trying to test a *.forward* you should send a test message from an account other than the gmail that is the target of the forward.

Comment: I asked a friend to send me a test mail and it worked. Now I try to find out in which cases Gmail ignores the mails. For example, when I send from myname@gmail.com to the very same address, it shows up in my inbox. From test@mydomain1.com to test@mydomain2.com does not even though it makes no sense to hide it when it's about two different addresses I would say.

Comment: Well, from the quoted text above, gmail checks if **Message-ID** was same or not. Otherwise, you should ask google :)